# Australia PR and career transition

Tags: resident-permit, australia, residency

I am an Indian citizen currently living in the US. I have a B. Comm in Management and PGDM (considered MBA in India) in finance and around 7 years of experience as equity/financial analyst.

In the last 6 months I have done a full stack development course here in the US and I have learned Python, MEAN and Ruby on Rails stacks as I am looking to transition into web development. Now my questions are

- Is is possible for me to migrate to Australia and at the same time make this career transition?
- if I were to apply for Australian PR would my background be considered for web developer skill.
- Financial analyst is also a select skill so is it possible to apply as an analyst and get a web developer job once I get there?

Thanks in advance for the responses.